# onBeforeRequest redirect not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension and I want to redirect certain URL's to another page.

For this I found the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` event handler, in the documentation is states that I can return a `redirectUri` to block the request and redirect it to another page, however when trying this I can't seem to get it working.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is my code (background script).

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(details => {
    console.log("Redirecting request: ", details.url);   // Logs the request
    return {redirectUrl: "/feed/subscriptions"};         // Doesn't redirect request
}, {
    "urls": [
        "https://www.youtube.com/"
    ],
    types: [
        "main_frame"
    ]
}, [
    "blocking"
]);
```

---

It ended up being a manifest issue, I edited my permissions to make them look like this:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://www.youtube.com/"
]
```

Comment: can u paste your extention's html file ?

Comment: @ahankendi my extension doesn't use any HTML files, it's purely script based

Comment: An actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. You should leave your question as it was originally, perhaps with clarification as to the *Question*, but not including an Answer within the Question. Create your own Answer with the code you used. [Answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), when you have solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you'll get chrome.webRequest element is undefined becuse of permission issue request permissions for the webRequest API is webRequest.

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
```

second think is url matching pattern may incorrect. 
try to use urls: ['*://www.youtube.com/']

Comment: Yup this was it, I also had to add `webRequestBlocking`, thanks!